# Cannot Call the Underscore.String Function `lpad` for Error `Uncaught TypeError: _.lpad is not a function`

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.string.js

I want to call the function `_.lpad('1', 2, '0')` but chrome shows me that `Uncaught TypeError: _.lpad is not a function`. I already included the script tags in the HTML file like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/3.3.4/underscore.string.min.js"></script>
```

If I call `console.log(_)`, it shows me:

```
>console.log(_)
function (n){return n instanceof m?n:this instanceof m?void(this._wrapped=n):new m(n)}
```

Can you tell me why and how to solve it?

Comment: What happens when you enter `console.log(_)`? Is _ defined?

Comment: @SOliver - Yes, it is defined.

Comment: It say that you use it as `lpad` and NOT `_.lpad` (http://epeli.github.io/underscore.string/#lpad-str-length-padstr-gt-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s.lpad('1', 2, '0')
```

underscore.string export as window.s in browser